# How to remove ViewModel Required before sending it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a view model with a "field" that is required.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

And in one of my controllers, I'm return that view model.
But, depending on some parameters, I want to remove the required.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    if(something){
        model.SomeThingToRemoveTheRequiredFromCode();
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

How can I remove the required from the view model in the situation where I just created the view model?

Comment: You can't remove an attribute from a class instance. Attributes belong to the type, not the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach. Create a new model without the Required attribute

```
public class MyViewModelToo
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

then in the condition, return the view using that view model

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    if(something){
        var modelToo = new MyViewModelToo();
        return View(modelToo);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove it from model-state dictionary like this

```
if(something){
    Modelstate.Remove("Code")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one field you can use this

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
var nmodel= new MyViewModel().fieldname;
if(something){
    return View(nmodel);
}
return View(model);
}
```

Or you can use @using System.Web.ModelBinding; in your class

```
ModelState.Remove("Code");
```